# The stabilizer of a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, topological-groups

Consider the Lie group action $G$ on the manifold $M$. Let $N$ be a submanifold of $M$. Let $G_N:=\{g\in G; g\cdot N\subseteq N\} $ be the stabilizer of $N$.

Is $G_N$ a Lie subgroup of $G$? How to prove that?

Comment: $G_N$ is not even a subgroup at all, no? Consider $M = \mathbb R$, $N=[0,\infty)$, $G = \mathbb R$ acting by translations.

Comment: Did you mean $gN=N$? Then $G_N$ is a Lie subgroup provided $N$ is a closed subset of $M$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen What if $N$ be any submanifold? Is $\{g\in G; gN=N\}$ a Lie subgroup?